# Find and delete near duplicate lines with certain punctuation

Tags: command-line, awk, perl, text-editing, deduplication

I have a text file with millions of lines. Some lines contain the same alphanumeric sequence, but differ in case and punctuation. I consider these lines duplicates. I want to remove any duplicate line containing periods but keep the other line (this other line will usually contain punctuation like underscore or dash)

Input:

```
000
111
12_34
12.34
123-456-789
123.456.789
A.B.C
a_b_c
qwerty
qwertx
abcdefghijklm.nopqrstuvwxy.z
a-B-cdeFghiJklmNopqRStuvwxy__Z
22.2
33.3
```

Desired output:

```
000
111
12_34
123-456-789
a_b_c
qwerty
qwertx
a-B-cdeFghiJklmNopqRStuvwxy__Z
22.2
33.3
```

Comment: Do you want to delete **all** lines that contain a dot?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear, it's been updated. No not all lines with periods. Basically it is: delete lines with periods if the line has the same alphanumeric sequence as another line.

Comment: How big is your file in GByte?

Comment: 600MB, 20 millions lines. I bet this is something awk can do but I've just learned the basics. I can list all duplicate lines by stripping the punctuation then uniq -id but this leaves me without punctuation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming the duplicate values are contiguous !

---

A perl script that does the job.

Not tested on big file!

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file1'; # path to input file
# read the input file in memory
open my $F, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file': $!";
my @list = <$F>;chomp @list;
# delete all . - _ from each line and add this new string in the array for comparison
my @res = map {my $tmp=$_; tr/._-//d; [lc$_,$tmp] } @list;
# memoize the first values
my $prev_tst = $res[0][0];  # contains the string without punctuation
my $prev_orig = $res[0][1]; # contains original string
# loop on other values
for my $ind (1 .. @res-1) {
    my ($tst, $orig) = ($res[$ind][0], $res[$ind][1]);
    # te string without punctuation is the same as the previous
    if ($tst eq $prev_tst) {
        # if the previous original value contains dot
        if ($prev_orig =~  tr/.//) {
            # delete it
            undef $res[$ind-1];
        # if the current original value contains dot
        } elsif ($orig =~ tr/.//) {
            # delete it
            undef $res[$ind];
        }
    }
    # memorize value for next step
    $prev_tst = $tst;
    $prev_orig = $orig;
}
# write result to result file
my $result = 'result_file'; # path to result file
open my $R, '>', $result or die "unable to open '$result': $!";

for (@res) {
    next unless defined $_; # skip undifned values
    print $R $_->[1],"\n";
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I need to learn perl. Every time I see a perl script I'm amazed. Plus it only took a few seconds to run on the large text file.

Comment: @Priora: Thanks. Perl is very efficient concerning string manipulation. You may consider upvoting the answer ;-)

Comment: I noticed on rather large lists that sorting order matters (values must be contiguous as you stated). Is there any way to make it check each line against the whole list instead of just its contiguous value?

Comment: @Priora: It is possible, but a little bit more complex. Instead of testing with previous encountered value, you have to add a loop that compare the currrent value with all other values.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
sed 's/\./-/g; s/__*/-/g' /path/to/infile | sort -u > /path/to/outfile
```

should do the trick

Comment: This will not delete the second line for `12_34` and `12.34`

Comment: Good catch! Edited the answer.

Comment: Another problem is that dot, dash & underscore are not always at the same place, look at the 2 lines before the last in the example. ;-(